# Click event on specific data index of a grid - Ext JS

Tags: javascript, function, extjs

So I have my grid, aliased as `widget.metadatalist`

I have one of my columns here:

```
{header: 'Lineage', dataIndex: 'popup', renderer: renderPopupIcon, flex: 1, tdCls: 'pop_cell', menuDisabled: true, id: 'lineage_button' }
```

Currently I have a Controller that listens for the click of any row/column in the grid, and performs the same action.

However, I want it to listen for only the specific dataindex (or column), and *then* execute the function.

Here's my controller

```
 this.control({
            'metadatalist': {
                click: this.viewDesc 
            }
        });...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 4.1+ has cellclick event that has a bunch of useful info in the event payload including the cellindex

```
cellclick( this, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts)
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick

Comment: This seems like it would work, how would I incorporate it into my controller and listen for the exact cell I want?

Comment: just like you had it already, its a single cell event listener - you just need to figure out in the handler whether or not you need to take any action. Alternatively you may use a specialized action column type, it already does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there anyway to pinpoint the exact cell from my widget? for example: 'metadatalist > (dataIndex)='value''